# Numbering nonconsecutive paragraphs in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, typesetting, formatting, paragraph

I have a project that requires that we primarily lay out a lot of text (think sections in an employee manual) with explanatory notes scattered throughout the document. We only want to number the explanatory notes sequentially throughout and to let the main text remain unnumbered. So it would look like:

Main text main text

1. Note note note

Main text main text

Main text main text

Main text main text

2. Note note note

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Definitely. You need to set up two separate styles:

- one style for simple text (not numbered)
- a copy of that style where you merely select 'Numbers' under 'Bullets and Numbering' section of this second paragraph style. the auto-numbering will work with everything else set by default under this panel
- further read: https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/bullets-numbering.html

[image]

[image]